# Inserting auto increment into database ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, mysql, sql, database, auto-increment

I'm trying to register a user, with the following query:

```
"INSERT INTO Users (Username, Password, FirstName, Surname, Age, HouseNumber, 
                    StreetName, Town, County, Postcode, TelephoneNumber, 
                   isBanned, isAdmin) 
 VALUES ('" + textboxUsername.Text + "','" + textboxPassword.Text + "','" + 
             textboxFirstName.Text + "','" + textboxSurname.Text + "','" + textboxAge.Text + "','" + textboxHouseNumber.Text + 
     "','" + textboxStreetName.Text + "','" + 
              textboxTown.Text + "','" + textboxCounty.Text + "','" + 
             textboxPostcode.Text + "','" + textboxTelephoneNumber.Text + 
          "', 'false', 'false')", con);
```

The database is set up as you would expect, with only the above values and UserID, which should be an auto increment value using Identity Specification. However, I get the following error:

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'UserID', table 'myFilePath'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
```

Why is this? I can't tell it to insert anything for the UserID as the database needs to handle that, currently the UserID is the primary key and as such can't be not null. What am I doing wrong? This used to work a few months ago

Comment: can you post the schema of `Users`? maybe you forgot to set auto-increment property on it.

Comment: Check if your auto-increment is setup. See this example: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: @JohnTotetWoo I don't know how to do that sorry, I'm relatively new, but I set "Identity Specification to Yes, (Is Identity) to Yes, Identity Increment to 1, Identity Seed to 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also mention `id` as `NULL` in query. It will get filled using `auto-increment`:

```
INSERT INTO Users 
(UserID, Username, Password, FirstName, Surname, Age, HouseNumber, StreetName, 
 Town, County, Postcode, TelephoneNumber, isBanned, isAdmin
) 
VALUES 
(NULL,'" + textboxUsername.Text + "','" + 
 textboxPassword.Text + "','" + textboxFirstName.Text + "','" + 
 textboxSurname.Text + "','" + textboxAge.Text + "','" + textboxHouseNumber.Text + "','" +
 textboxStreetName.Text + "','" + textboxTown.Text + "','" + textboxCounty.Text + "','" +
 textboxPostcode.Text + "','" + textboxTelephoneNumber.Text + "', 'false', 'false')", 
 con);
```

Also check for the data type of field `UserID` It should be something like this:

```
UserID INT unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```

Comment: writing your query by including `userid` with `null value` is the same as writing it without `userid`. the OP, i think, forgot to set the userid auto-increment property oh the table.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have a sequence on you column, if not add one:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE yourschemaname.Users
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1;
GO
```

Comment: I think OP is asking for MySQL query.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQL AUTO INCREMENT:

define your table with AUTO_INCREMENT:

```
CREATE TABLE Users
(
UserID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Username varchar(255) NOT NULL,
Password varchar(255) ,
.....
PRIMARY KEY (UserID)
)
```

and then do your insert:

```
INSERT INTO Users (Username, Password, FirstName, Surname, Age, HouseNumber, 
                    StreetName, Town, County, Postcode, TelephoneNumber, 
                   isBanned, isAdmin)
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp

Answer (score 1):

Can't believe I'm having to do this, but the database connection path was wrong. Sorry guys, I had a letter missing. I'll upvote everyone, and "answer" myself so people can see.